# Why can't I set the focus to an ASP.Net TextBox control in Javascript or from code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to set the focus to a TextBox control (which is inside an UpdatePanel) in an ASP.Net application (C#). I've tried the following in the code behind:

```
tbxName.Focus();
Page.SetFocus(tbxName);
tsmManageTables.SetFocus(tbxName);
```

None of those worked, so then I went to Javascript. Here's my Javascript function:

```
function SetControlFocus(ctrlID) {
  var ctrl = document.getElementById(ctrlID);
  ctrl.focus();
}
```

Here's the method in code behind that's calling it:

```
private void SetControlFocus(Control ctrl)
{
  StringBuilder focus = new StringBuilder();
  focus.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  focus.AppendFormat("  SetControlFocus('{0}');" + System.Environment.NewLine, ctrl.ClientID);
  focus.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "setControlFocus", focus.ToString(), false);
}
```

And the call:

```
SetControlFocus(tbxName);
```

I've also tried the Javascript:

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrlID) {
    var ctrl = $('<%= ' + ctrlID + ' %>');
    ctrl.focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

With either version of the Javascript function, I get the error

> "Object ctl00_MainContent_tbxName has no method 'focus'"

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I tried Karl's suggestion of using a class selector instead of the ID selector with the ugly `<%= =>`, but it didn't work. Now I'm getting a different error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: className is not defined

with the Javascript:

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrlClass) {
    var ctrl = $('.' + ctrlClass);
    ctrl.focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

the markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxName" runat="server" CssClass="className"></asp:TextBox>
```

the calling method:

```
private void SetControlFocus(Control ctrl)
{
  StringBuilder focus = new StringBuilder();
  focus.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  focus.AppendFormat("  SetControlFocus({0});" + System.Environment.NewLine, ctrl.CssClass);
  focus.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "setControlFocus", focus.ToString(), false);
}
```

the call (C#):

```
SetControlFocus(tbxName);
```

and the generated HTML for the TextBox:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxName" type="text" id="ctl00_MainContent_tbxName" class="className" />
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I played around some more with this and made progress (I think). Now I'm not getting any error messages, but the focus still isn't going to the TextBox. Here's my current jQuery function:

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrl) {
    //give the control focus
    alert(ctrl);
    ctrl.focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And here's the C# method where I call it:

```
private void SetControlFocus(TextBox ctrl)
{
  StringBuilder focus = new StringBuilder();
  focus.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  focus.AppendFormat("  SetControlFocus({0});" + System.Environment.NewLine, ctrl.ClientID);
  focus.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "setControlFocus", focus.ToString(), false);
} //end method SetControlFocus
```

Notice that I'm passing the control's ClientID to the Javascript function. The weird thing is that the Javascript is taking the ClientID and actually "capturing" the control object, rather than a string containing the ClientID. The alert is working, it gives me `[object HTMLInputElement]` in the alert. Any tips?

**UPDATE 3**:

I've modified the Javascript function:

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrlSelector) {
    alert(ctrlSelector);
    $(ctrlSelector).focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

and the calling method:

```
private void SetControlFocus(TextBox ctrl)
{
  StringBuilder focus = new StringBuilder();
  focus.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  focus.AppendFormat("  SetControlFocus('{0}');" + System.Environment.NewLine, "#" + ctrl.ClientID);
  focus.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "setControlFocus", focus.ToString(), false);
}
```

(notice the addition of single quotes around the argument - `'{0}'`).

Now I'm getting the correct selector (the alert responds with `#ctl00_MainContent_txtName`), no errors, but the TextBox *still* isn't getting focus.

Comment: First of all, in jquery you need to put # prefix before ClientID

Comment: can you post the html that gets generated for the textbox?

Comment: @JuanC. Sure - I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to make this work! I moved the jQuery `SetControlFocus()` call into another jQuery function that I'm calling from my code behind. The code behind method calls `MessageDialog()`, which now looks like this:

```
(function($) {
  MessageDialog = function(title, dialogText, focusID) {
    //add the dialog div to the page
    $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='messageDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));
    //create the dialog
    $('#messageDialog').dialog({
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      close: function(event, ui) { $('body').find('#messageDialog').remove(); },
      buttons:
        [{
          text: 'OK',
          click: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
          //Set focus to the control object in argument #3 (if provided)
            if (focusID.length > 0) {
              SetControlFocus(focusID);
            }
          }
        }]
      });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

`SetControlFocus()` remains:

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrlSelector) {
    $(ctrlSelector).focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And my calling method in C# (which is an overload of a method I already had) is:

```
private void DisplayMessageDialog(string msgTitle, string msgText, string ctrlID)
{
  StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
  msg.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  msg.AppendFormat("  MessageDialog('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');" +
    System.Environment.NewLine, msgTitle, msgText, "#" + ctrlID);
  msg.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messageDialog", msg.ToString(), false);
} //end method DisplayMessageDialog (overload #2 - specifies a control to get focus
  //after the dialog is dismissed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second javascript is missing the hash sign to denote the ID selection.

```
(function($) {
  SetControlFocus = function(ctrlID) {
    var ctrl = $('#<%= ' + ctrlID + ' %>');
    ctrl.focus();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I should have caught that, thanks. However, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` for an ID selector.

Either do this:

```
var ctrl = $('#<%= ' + ctrlID + ' %>');
```

Or use a `class` name in your ASP.NET `TextBox` control instead, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="TheTextBox" />
```

Now your selector becomes this:

```
var ctrl = $('.TheTextBox');
```

Note: Using class selectors versus ID selectors greatly simplifies the selector syntax and removes the gnarly embedded code block (`<%= ... %>`) syntax you were using. While it is not as fast as an ID selector, the gains of simpler and more maintainable code are definitely worth it in my mind.

UPDATE:

Wrap the entire selector value in single quotes, like this:

```
var ctrl = $("'." + ctrlClass + "'");
```

Comment: OK, I tried this. Now I'm getting a different Javascript error: "className is not defined" (see the update in the OP for context).

Comment: See `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: Damn. That should have worked, but it didn't. I'm really stumped here.

Comment: @timbck2 - same error message? If you put an `alert(ctrlClass);` right before the selector line, what does that produce?

Comment: Yes, the same error message. The alert isn't happening - but the script *is* being called, because I put a breakpoint in and it stopped.

Comment: Where did you put the break point? It sounds like if the `alert()` is not firing then the `SetControlFocus` function is not firing, correct?

Comment: I put the break point on the `alert()`, which is inside the `SetControlFocus` function. So the function is firing.

Comment: I got a bit further, please see my new update above.